# adding calculated var to script breaks the script

Tags: javascript

I have this working fine

```
var oemdc1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("vehicle_oem_draw").value);        
var oemdc2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("vehicle_added_draw").value);
var oemdc3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("new_vehicle_draw").value);
var oemdc4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("prism_draw").value);
var oemdc5 = 1.2;
var total_current_draw = document.getElementById("total_hourly_current_draw");
                    (total_current_draw.value = oemdc1 + oemdc2 + oemdc3 + oemdc4 + oemdc5).toFixed(2);
```

Now I need to change the var assignment of oemdc5

I put this code

```
var bc_sd_calc = parseFloat(document.getElementById("battery_type").value);
var bc_sd = (((total_current_storage * bc_sd_calc) / 30) / 24).toFixed(5);
```

above the working code and change the var assignment from

```
var oemdc5 = 1.2;
```

to

```
var oemdc5 = bc_sd;
```

and that breaks the script.

I have also tried

var oemdc5 = bc_sd.value;

but in all cases my results fields in my form change to

NaN (which I know means it's not finding a number somewhere).

The optiongroup that I get the battery_type from is

```
<select name="battery_type" id="battery_type" size="1" >
<optgroup label="Battery chemistry type">
<option value="3.2404"></option>
<option value="2.1603"></option>
<option value="1.6205"></option>
<option value="0.00001"></option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Any tips/help is appreciated.

WD./

Comment: What is `bc_sd` when it runs the calculation? Note that `toFixed` returns a string.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a [runnable example](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) from your code?

Comment: It's big page with 90% of the script working and my just fine-tuning things so would just add more confusion (I think).

Comment: *"breaks the script"* isn't much of a problem description. What errors are thrown and where?

Comment: I used @Evan Trimboli's advice and removed the toFixed() code but that did not fix it.

Comment: @WyattsDad You should familiarize yourself with the debugger, it will allow you to step through the code as it's running.

Answer (score 0):

`bc_sd` is a string (created using `toFixed`).

... try ...

```
var oemdc5 = parseFloat(bc_sd);
```